# How to access configurations specified in XML of a jetty server from code

Tags: java, xml, jetty

I've a jetty Server, what I want to configure for HTTPS traffic, I could do this, just simply modified some XML, and ini files (since this IoC is the preferred way), however I would like to access to some of these things which were configured in the xml from other classes, this is in the xml:

```
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStoreType">PKCS12</Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default="etc/keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default="OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4"/></Set>
...
```

What I want is to call the sslContextFactory.getKeyStorePath() function somewhere in my codebase. But where is this sslContextFactory instance, where can I find it, how can I have a reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on what you are asking, but I am going to take a stab at it anyway. It sounds like you are familiar with running Jetty as a distribution and editing Jetty XML and ini files but now want to use some of the Jetty functionality as part of your embedded code?

For `SSLContextFactory` specifically, the class is included as part of the `jetty-util` jar file that comes with the [distribution](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/). You could also download that jar file by itself on [Maven Central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/).

The official documentation for Jetty includes several examples of embedded Jetty functionality. This [page](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html) may help you, specifically the example on [Multiple Connectors](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyConnectors.java), which uses SSL.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It doesn't answer my question, try to clarify more: I use XMLs and ini files to configure my jetty server, since it's not embedded into my app, it's a standalone server. So above in my question with that xml I create a sslContextFactory instance, with parameters. My question is how can I have a reference to that sslContextFactory instance, in my code, example in foo.java, because I want to get the keystore path, or I want to call reload() on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is not likely to be able to access the jetty standalone server's SSLContextFactory. Jetty by definition can host multiple applications at the same time, and acts like a container for those java web applications.

One option may be to use the embedded jetty server  ([a solution here](https://danielflower.github.io/2017/04/08/Lets-Encrypt-Certs-with-embedded-Jetty.html)), where you can start the jetty server within a java application (e.g. a jar package) and hold the references to your SSLContextFactory instance so that you can reload it whenever you like.

Another option may be using the maven jetty runner, again from another customized application, controlling the SslContextFactory yourself. This I cannot confirm at the moment, bu will update you as soon as I try it.